# Get a value from Chainable

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

At present time i am returning Chainable however i would like to just return a number.

If i do the following the value is undefined

```
static get tableRowsQuantity(): number {
    let countOfElements = 0;
    cy.get<HTMLElement>('tr.cdk-row.table-row').then(($rows) => {
      countOfElements = $rows.length;
    });
    return countOfElements;
  }
```

This works however it returns Chainable number instead of number

```
static get tableRowsQuantity(): Cypress.Chainable<number> {
    return cy.get<HTMLElement>('tr.cdk-row.table-row').then(($rows) => {
      let countOfElements = 0;
      countOfElements = $rows.length;
      return countOfElements;
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is **really bad practice** - you should not pass around Chainable results - they will become invalid if some action changes the DOM, and you will find yourself with an error you can't understand.

Answer (score 1):

`Chainable<T>` type has a function `then` that accepts a callback with a T value argument.
So you can use your function as follows:

```js
   tableRowsQuantity().then(tableRowsQuantity => {
      cy.log(tableRowsQuantity) // do whatever you want with the number
   })
```